# Undefined method `roles'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I'm having issues seeding my database with the default roles of my users.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :username
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  validates_presence_of :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  validates_uniqueness_of :username, :email

  before_create :setup_default_role_for_new_users

  ROLES = %w[admin default]

  private

  def setup_default_role_for_new_users
    self.roles = [ "default" ]
  end
end
```

**Seeds.rb**

```
puts 'Loading seed data now....'
user1 = User.create(:username => 'admin',   :email => 'testing@email.com', :password => 'qweasd',:password_confirmation => 'qweasd', :role => 'admin')
user2 = User.create(:username => 'userone', :email => 'user1@email.com', :password => 'qweasd', :password_confirmation => 'qweasd')
user3 = User.create(:username => 'usertwo', :email => 'user2@email.com', :password => 'qweasd',:password_confirmation => 'qweasd')
puts 'Users added'
```

When seeding the error I get:

```
undefined method `roles' for #<User:0x53f4c60>
```

I have have the `role` column in my database so why wouldn't it work?

Comment: Because you don't have a `roles` method, called in `setup_default_role_for_new_users`?

Comment: @DaveNewton Yeah I know but  I though `ROLES` defined there would be enough. How would I define a `role` method for this scenario, that is to make users assigned with the `default` role when they sign up?

Comment: `ROLES` is just a constant; if you have a `role` column, the attribute is `role`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add :roles to your attr_accessible if you want to be able to mass assign it like in:

```
user1 = User.create(:username => 'admin',   :email => 'testing@email.com', :password => 'qweasd',:password_confirmation => 'qweasd', :role => 'admin')
```

also is it `:role` or `:roles` ? Check your database, if you have `:role` or `:roles` paste your schema.db here.

Comment: I have `:role` but if I mass assignment like so, Isn't it dangerous to allow that if I don't want to allow users to assign roles at all?

Comment: Yes it's dangerous so don't allow it. But then you can't mass assign it either. Seeds.rb will need to assign the attribute like user1.role => 'admin'

Comment: My mistake it is `role` so I had to change it to `self.role = [ "default" ]`, I missed it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

because you use the

```
before_create :setup_default_role_for_new_users.
```

First you set the user1 to admin (in memory) and then the before_create sets it to default

Something like this should do it

```
before_create :setup_default_role_for_new_users, :if => :not_user1


def not_user1
  username != "admin"
end
```